# Fail to create dataset using azure sdk python for azure data factory

Tags: azure, dataset, azure-data-factory, azure-sdk-python

I am trying to create dataset in ADF using azure sdk for python, unfortunately I am running into this error message. I am not sure what is wrong with my code below.

```
dsOut_name = 'POC_DatasetName'
ds_ls ="AzureBlobStorage"
output_blobpath = '/tempdir'
df_name = 'pipeline1'
dsOut_azure_blob = AzureBlobDataset(linked_service_name=ds_ls, folder_path=output_blobpath)
dsOut = adf_client.datasets.create_or_update(rg_name, df_name, dsOut_name, dsOut_azure_blob)
print_item(dsOut)
```

```
Error Message: SerializationError: Unable to build a model: Unable to deserialize to object: type, AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get', DeserializationError: Unable to deserialize to object: type, AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Help Please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce your issue, this line `ds_ls ="AzureBlobStorage"` is wrong, it should be `ds_ls = LinkedServiceReference(reference_name=ls_name)`.

[image]

You could refer to my complete working sample.

Make sure your service principal has an RBAC role(e.g `Owner`,`Contributor`) in the `Access control (IAM)` of your data factory and you have done all the [**Prerequisites**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/quickstart-create-data-factory-python#prerequisites).

My package version:

```
azure-mgmt-datafactory  0.6.0
azure-mgmt-resource  3.1.0
azure-common  1.1.23
```

---

Code:

```
from azure.common.credentials import ServicePrincipalCredentials
from azure.mgmt.resource import ResourceManagementClient
from azure.mgmt.datafactory import DataFactoryManagementClient
from azure.mgmt.datafactory.models import *


subscription_id = '<subscription-id>'
ls_name = 'storageLinkedService'
rg_name = '<group-name>'
df_name = '<datafactory-name>'

credentials = ServicePrincipalCredentials(client_id='<client id of the service principal>',
                                          secret='<secret of the service principal>', tenant='<tenant-id>')
resource_client = ResourceManagementClient(credentials, subscription_id)
adf_client = DataFactoryManagementClient(credentials, subscription_id)


storage_string = SecureString('DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=<storage account name>;AccountKey=<storage account key>')

ls_azure_storage = AzureStorageLinkedService(connection_string=storage_string)
ls = adf_client.linked_services.create_or_update(rg_name, df_name, ls_name, ls_azure_storage)

ds_ls = LinkedServiceReference(reference_name=ls_name)


# Create an Azure blob dataset (output)
dsOut_name = 'ds_out'
output_blobpath = '<container name>/<folder name>'
dsOut_azure_blob = AzureBlobDataset(linked_service_name=ds_ls, folder_path=output_blobpath)
dsOut = adf_client.datasets.create_or_update(rg_name, df_name, dsOut_name, dsOut_azure_blob)
print(dsOut)
```

[image]